# Height of UITableView depending on its cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, autolayout

I have `UITableView`. Its cell contains `UITextView` and their height is dynamic. pic:

[image: storyboard]

If **I create the constraint** 268 px for `UITableView` height it is constant and there are free space after all cells. Pic:

[image: uitableview]

**Without height constraint** the height become 0. pic:

[image]

I want height of `UITableView` to match cells exactly.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For creating rows with dynamic height based on the content you need to have the content(in your case it's text), calculate the height required for the text to display. Also if the text is large/small you can enforce a limit on the max/min height of the cell.

Inside the table delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
      // calculate the height of the cell based on the size of the text required to be displayed

CGSize textViewSize = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:20] 
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(WIDHT_OF_VIEW, FLT_MAX) 
                       lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
// WIDHT_OF_VIEW could be text view's width and  FLT_MAX could be 10,000

CGFloat cellHeight = 50.0f; // initialize with minimum cell height

cellHeight = cellHeight + textViewSize.height;

//you can set MAX_HEIGHT_OF_CELL
if(cellHeight > MAX_HEIGHT_OF_CELL)
{
    return MAX_HEIGHT_OF_CELL;// set the text view to scroll vertically while creating cell
    }
else
{
    return cellHeight;
}
}
```

Similarly when you are creating the cell in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   Cell *cell;
    ....
    ....

   CGFloat cellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   cell.textView setFrame:CGRectMake (cell.textView.frame.origin.x, cell.textView.frame.origin.y, cell.textView.frame.size.width, cellHeight - 50.0f)

...
...

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve is probably a bad Idea as you need to be careful to not have a UITableView bigger than the screen or you shouldn't be able to scroll. A probably better approach would be:
* Set the height of the tableView to your needs.
* Don't use separator in the tableView
* Include the separator as a view inside the cells if you need them.

With that approach you will end with a table with not visible extra rows that can scroll to all the cells and with the right layout.

If you still want to calculate the size of the tableView to be the same of the cells you can set the frame or the constraint after call [self.tableView reloadData] (depends if you use autolayout or not) but I discourage this approach unless you have a very good reason to do so.

```
//example
-(void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad]
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
// Max height is 268;
if (self.tableView.contentSize.height<=268){
//tableHeightConstraint is an IBOutlet to the height Constraint.
tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
}else{
tableHeightConstraint.constant = 268;
}
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
}
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to notice to notice that there are a `UIScrollView` that contains everything (including `UITableView`). So `UITableView` can be bigger than the screen. I inserted `tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;` and `[self.view setNeedsLayout]` in `viewWillAppear` and `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewDidLoad`, but that does not work. The height of `UITableView` does not match cells.

Comment: Can you post an image of what you want to achieve and / or some example project?